# Pullback bundle for isomorphic bundles gives one of the bundles?

Tags: general-topology, vector-bundles

If we have that $\alpha,\beta$ are isomorphic bundles, say $p_1:E_1\to B_1$ and $p_2:E_2\to B_2$ respectively, then there is a map $f:B_1\to B_2$ that is the identity map, and we get that:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}E_1& \overset{F}{\to} &E_2\\ \downarrow&&\downarrow\\B_1&\overset{f}{\to}&B_2\end{array}$$

Is the pullback bundle $f^*E_2$ the same thing as $E_1$?

It seems we obtain $f^*E_2$ (which is completely a notational choice right) where $$f^*E_2=\{(b,e):b\in B_1,p_2(e)=f(b)\}$$
Now since $f$ is the identity, this pullback bundle has in it's total space elements $(b,e)$ where $p_2(e)=b$, and we can see that the square of this pullback bundle commutes, since $$\pi_2(F((b,e)))=\pi_2(e)=b=f(b)=f(\pi_1((b,e))$$
and so this pullback bundle is isomorphic to $\beta$ and thus isomorphic to $\alpha$ if the linear isomorphisms of fibers also holds, is that logic correct so far?

Comment: Yes everything you wrote is correct.

Comment: Now we want $F$ mapping between the pullback bundle and the original bundle to give us linear isomorphisms of the fibers. So we look at $p_1^{-1}(b)\cong \{b\}\times \Bbb R^n$ by the local trivializations, if $F$ mapped this, it would immediately give us $F:\{b\}\times \Bbb R^n \mapsto \Bbb R^n\cong \{b\}\times \Bbb R^n = \{f(b)\}\times \Bbb R^n$ and we would be done. (Being pedantic perhaps in regard to the $F$ mapping), but otherwise we can immediately see $$p_1^{-1}(b)\cong \{b\}\times \Bbb R^n = \{f(b)\}\times \Bbb R^n \cong p_2^{-1}(f(b))$$

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier. This is again correct, but I don't think it is really enlighting to look pullback over the identity mapping ...